# mamp server cannot open localhost

Tags: browser, safari, localhost, mamp

In *mamp*,*apache* and *mysql* runs ,but in browser localhost does not work.

It displays like this,

```
safari cannot open the page "localhost:8888/mamp because safari cannot find the server localhost.
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Check Your Server is running ??? As it seems, safari can't find the local host. Sometimes the port may be wrong. Are you sure it's 8888 ?